# Post increment operator, left hand side, character pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Considering variable `s` defined as follows:

```
CHAR *s;
```

I am trying to understand the behavior of the following code:

```
while ( *s )
  if ( *s++ == ' ' )
    break;
```

Is this equivalent to the following (option 1)?

```
while ( *s )
  if ( *s == ' ' ) {
    *s++;
    break;
  }
```

Or, is it equivalent to the following (option 2)?

```
while ( *s ) {
  *s++;
  if ( *s == ' ' )
    break;
}
```

I'm trying to understand the defined behavior of the `++` operator on the left-hand side of the assignment statement.

### **EDIT**

Oops! Thank you to the responders. I put too many `*` operators in my original Option 1 and Option 2 (I don't write in C every day).

What I *meant* to write for the Options 1 and 2 are the following.

Option 1:

```
while ( * s ) {
  if ( *s = ' ' ) {
    s++;
    break;
  }
  s++;
}
```

Option 2:

```
while ( *s ) {
  s++;
  if ( *s = ' ' )
    break;
}
```

In other words: Does the pointer incrementing (`s++`) happen as if it was written before the `if` and dereference/character comparison, or after?

If I understand, Option 1 would be correct, and basically equivalent to this:

```
char *s;
char c;

while ( *s ) {
  c = *s++;
  if ( c = ' ' )
    break;
}
```

Comment: Neither – option 1 only increments once and would end up in an endless loop if initial `*s` is not a space; option 2 skips checking very first character (so wouldn't stop if that one is a space, in contrast original version) and additionally, if finding a space, remains on that while original version points to the subsequent character. An equivalent version would look like: `while(*s) { char c = *s; ++s; if(c == ' ') { break; } }`.

Comment: You could do as well: `while(*s && *s != ' ') { ++s; } s += *s == ' ';` – for all these variants: It doesn't matter if you use `++s` or `s++`, they result in the same here, and dereferencing `s` without using the value is obsolete anyway, so no `*++s` or `*s++` needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `CHAR *` => `char *`
2. `*s++` => `s++` as `*s++` increments the pointer after dereferencing it (which in this case is a no-op. The idea of this operation is to increment the pointer.
3. It is not an equivalent of any codes you have posted. It is:

```
while ( *s )
{
  char c = *s++;
  if ( c == ' ' ) break;
}


while ( *s )
{
  char c = *s;
  s += 1; // s++;
  if ( c == ' ' ) break;
}
```

or

```
while ( *s )
{
  if ( *s == ' ' ) {s++; break;}
  s++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not equivalent to either of your variants. It's more like

```
while (s[0] != '\0')
{
    // Save the current pointer
    char *orig_pointer = s;

    // Increase the pointer, making it point to the next character
    s = s + 1;

    // Compare the character pointed to by the original pointer
    if (orig_pointer[0] == ' ')
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is actually easily understandable and a huge improvement over using the `++` operator just to cram everything into as few unreadable lines as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
*s++;
```

has a nonsense dereferencing of the pointer.  The `++` at the right of the pointer has higher precedence than the dereference on the left, making the increment to be applied to the pointer, and not to the pointed value (which is lost and not used)  This makes the statement

```
*s++ = something;
```

actually equivalent to

```
*s = something;
s++;
```

based on this, we can dismantle the snippet you post

```
while ( *s )
  if ( *s++ == ' ' )
    break;
```

into the following sequence

```
while ( *s != 0 ) /* redundant, but more readable */
    if ( *s == ' ' ) {
        s++;  /* we still need to increment the pointer after comparing the value */
        break;
    }
    s++;  /* and here we need also to increment, because we exited the loop in the break above */
}
```

but we cannot use the construct:

```
while ( *s ) {
  if ( *s == ' ' ) {
    *s++;
    break;
  }
  /* the pointer should have been incremented also here */
}
```

nor

```
while ( *s ) {
  *s++;    /* WRONG WRONG WRONG, see comment below */
  if ( *s == ' ' )  /* the tested element is the one after incrementing the pointer, and not before */
    break;
}
```

If you check the original code, you will see that the pointer increment is the last operation done always you enter the loop (even if you exit because you found a space being pointed by the pointer)  You could unloop the last
iteration in case you want an alternate way of saying and (despite I expect some complaints) say:

```
while (*s != 0 && *s != ' ')
    s++;
/* here, *s == 0 || *s == ' ', in the second case we should increment the pointer we didn't inside the loop */
if (*s == ' ')
    s++;
```

This code is equivalent to the one you posted first, and probably there will be other ways to simplify.